# How to approximately diagonalize a special symmetric hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, hermitian-matrices

Given a hermitian matrix $H$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    H^1 & V^{12}  \\
    V^{21} & H^2  
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Here, $H^1,H^2\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ are diagonal (or block-diagonal) matrices, $V^{12}={V^{21}}^\dagger \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$. When N is very large, is there exists some methods allowing me to get the approximated eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $H$?

Intuitively, it seems the diagonal structure of $H^1,H^2$ is helpful, maybe by constructing an isomorphism between $H$ and the tensor product $H^1 \otimes H^2$ and then docomposite $H^1$ or $H^2$ as a direct sum:
\begin{equation}
H^1 \otimes H^2 = \oplus_{i}(H^1_i\otimes H^2)=\oplus_{j}(H^1\otimes H^2_j).
\end{equation}
But I am not sure whether it is truely helpful. And I don't know how to constructe such isomorphism with a general $V^{12}$.

Comment: Notice that up to a block-diagonal orthogonal basis change, $H$  is any Hermitian matrix, so probably any specialized diagonalizing algorithm isn't more efficient than the general ones